# how to parse xml in iPhone ,

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing

i have string which contain xml responce , (asmx web service) 
i am parsing xml through APXML lib. 
when i get root element that give me body tag , i do not want body tag , i want to get my actual data that is in Root tag and than child tag .. 
please tell me how to get data from this.. thanks .. my xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <loginFunctionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <loginFunctionResult>
   <Root xmlns="">
    <child>
     <id>52</id>
     <name>mohsin</name>
   </child>
  </Root>
 </loginFunctionResult>
</loginFunctionResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and my code is ..

```
NSString *resultString=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[resultData bytes] length:resultData.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result string: %@",resultString);

APDocument *doc = [APDocument documentWithXMLString:resultString];

APElement *rootElement = [doc rootElement];
NSArray *childElement = [rootElement childElements];

for (APElement *chile in childElement) {


    NSLog(@"chid name %@",chile.name);
    NSLog(@"chile value %@",chile.value);
}
```

that give me result this ..

```
 chid name soap:Body
 chile value (null)
```

Comment: That XML element has no value, it simply has another child.

Comment: how to get child tag element ? thank

Comment: Do you need it to be spoonfed?  Look at how you got the child elements from the root element and apply that logic.

Comment: @mohsinraza Look at my answer. You just need to recursively call `childElements` on every child, until they don't have any more children

Answer (score 2):

`childElements` is not recursive and it will return only the direct descendands of the root element.

So in this case the only child element is the tag `<loginFunctionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">`, whose value is null since it doesn't have any content but only one child.

If you want to parse the whole tree, you should recursively call `childElements` on every child until you get to the leaves (elements without children).

Comment: i am beginner in ios , if you give me link any example how to parse whole tree . thanks

Comment: This has nothing specific about iOS. It's general programming.